# how to invoke a struts action from sjg grid using a cell edit

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Im trying to edit a cell in sjg:grid cell and when done it should invoke the editControlParam URL , but rather it invokes the table URL , reloading the table ,I have an  sjg:grid in my jsp markup

```
 <s:url id="controlParameterTableURL" namespace="/global" action="loadControlParametersTable"/>
 <s:url id="editParameterUrl" namespace="/global" action="editControlParameter"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <sjg:grid id="controlparameterGrid" caption="%{getText('controlparametersearch.title')}" dataType="json" href="%{controlParameterTableURL}" pager="true"
                          gridModel="controlParameterList"
                          rowList="%{session.sessionAttr.pref.tableRowlist}"
                          rowNum="15"
                          rownumbers="true"
                          viewrecords="true"
                          cellEdit="true"
                          cellurl="%{editParameterUrl}"
                          onSelectRowTopics="rowselect" gridview="true"
                          onGridCompleteTopics="gridComplete" footerrow="true"
                          >
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" align='left' index="id" title='Id' hidden="true"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn width="200" name="code" align='left' index="code" title='%{getText("controlparameteraction.controlparametercode")}' sortable="true"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn width="200" name="name" align='left' index="nName" title='%{getText("controlparameteraction.controlparametername")}' sortable="true"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn  editrules="{required: true}"  editable="true" width="200" name="value" align='left' index="name" title='%{getText("controlparameteraction.controlparametervalue")}' sortable="true"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn width="200" name="status" cssStyle='text-align:right' hidden='true' index="status" title='%{getText("model.status")}'/>
                </sjg:grid>
```

and this in my struts xml

```
    <action name="editControlParameter" method="editControlParameter" class="controlParameterAction">
        <result name="success">/pages/global/globalbase.jsp?nextpath=/pages/global/&amp;nextpage=controlparam
        </result>
        <result name="error">/pages/global/globalbase.jsp?nextpath=/pages/global/&amp;nextpage=controlparam
        </result>
    </action>
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue by add @SkipValidation on the method (from struts2-core-x.x.x.jar)

```
@SkipValidation
public String editControlParameter() throws Exception{

    ControlParameterData data = ((ControlParameterData) getData());

    UserIdentificationToken userId = getUserIdentificationToken(getServletRequest());
    ControlParameterData d = controlParameterService.findControlParameterByPK(data.getId(), userId);
    d.setValue(data.getValue());
    ControlParameterData createdData = controlParameterService.modifyControlParameter(d, userId);
    setDataParameters(d, createdData);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Having to work for an organization maintaining legacy codes ,this is what you face